# How can I search by values from CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I added a CASE statement to get values for Invoice Status that will show up in a report. I now want to be able to search by InvoiceStatus values (open, paid, partial) in the report. I've tried a few things but I can't get anything to work. Any idea how to do this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Extranet_ClientMatterInvoices]
@BeginDate VARCHAR(max) = NULL,
@EndDate VARCHAR(max) = NULL,
@InvoiceStatus VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

AS
SELECT m.ClientGroupID,
m.ClientID,
m.ClientName,
m.MatterCode,
m.[Area Of Law],
i.InvoiceNo,
i.InvoiceTotalAmount,
i.InvoiceFees,
i.InvoiceCosts,
m.mattername,
i.invoiceDate,
 CASE 
  WHEN i.InvoiceTotalAmount <= 0 THEN 'Paid'
  WHEN i.Total_PaidWithWO = 0 THEN 'Open'
  WHEN i.Total_PaidWithWO < i.InvoiceTotalAmount THEN 'Partial'
  WHEN i.Total_PaidWithWO >= i.InvoiceTotalAmount THEN 'Paid'
ELSE 'Open'
END AS 'InvoiceStatus'
 FROM [local].[lp2warehouse].dbo.lp2_matters m
 INNER JOIN [local].[lp2warehouse].dbo.lp2_invoices i 
ON m.mattercode = i.mattercode
WHERE (i.invoicedate BETWEEN ISNULL(@BeginDate,'01/01/1900') 
AND ISNULL(@EndDate,'12/31/9999'))
ORDER BY m.ClientGroupID,m.ClientID
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the existing `SELECT` into a derived table or CTE, and then you can use the projected alias `InvoiceStatus` in the `WHERE` filter of an outer query, viz

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT 
   m.ClientGroupID,
   m.ClientID,
   ... other fields
   CASE 
     WHEN i.InvoiceTotalAmount <= 0 THEN 'Paid'
     WHEN i.Total_PaidWithWO = 0 THEN 'Open'
     WHEN i.Total_PaidWithWO < i.InvoiceTotalAmount THEN 'Partial'
     WHEN i.Total_PaidWithWO >= i.InvoiceTotalAmount THEN 'Paid'
     ELSE 'Open'
   END AS InvoiceStatus
 FROM ... same
 WHERE ... same
) derived
WHERE derived.InvoiceStatus = 'Partial';
```

Comment: Why he can not add filter condition on main query without derived query?

Comment: That worked perfectly. I've never used a derived table before. I'll have to remember this.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya thats how the standard works (and practically, `WHERE` will be processed before the derived columns get projected and thus are not yet available). You can however use aliases in other clauses, notably `ORDER BY` - perhaps you were thinking of that?